# Disable Helper Function Not Updating When Changes Are Made

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Here's The Code I'm Working With:

```
function TodoCard() {
  const taskArray = [
    { todo: "pancakes", completed: false, id: 1 },
    { todo: "cornflakes", completed: false, id: 2 },
    { todo: "bananas", completed: false, id: 3 },
  ];

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(taskArray);

  function disabledHelper(task) {
    return task.completed === true ? true : false;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return (
          <Button
            className="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            size="large"
            onClick={() => {
              task.completed = !task.completed;
              console.log(task.completed);
            }}
            key={task.todo}
            disabled={disabledHelper(task)}
          >
            {task.todo}
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My goal is to click a button, change "completed" to true and have the button become disabled as a result. The console log on the onclick verified for me that it was working, however the disableHelper function only runs when the page loads.

I tried inserting a useEffect but it throws errors because I'm putting it here:

```
disabled={useEffect(task => {
disableHelper(task)
})}
```

I'm convinced I have to find a way to put the useEffect elsewhere, or try a new method all together so the helper runs when I click the button

Any ideas on how I can get this to work as I want?

Comment: You should not be mutating state directly in your onClick handler. To trigger a rerender, you should call setTasks() to update the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is you are directly mutating your state object, so your component isn't being rerendered with updated state to recompute the disabled status.

## Solution

Update your state correctly. Use a functional state update to shallow copy the previous state into a new array. If the current task id matches then shallow copy the task and toggle the completed status, otherwise return the task.

```
const toggleCompleted = id => {
  setTasks(tasks => tasks.map(task => {
    return task.id === id ? {
      ...task,
      completed: !task.completed
    } : task;
  }));
};
```

The `disabledHelper` utility is also completely redundant since `task.completed` is already a boolean you can simply return it, or even more straight forward, set the `disabled` attribute directly.

I also would suggest using the task's `id` property as there's likely a better guarantee on uniqueness.

```
{tasks.map((task) => {
  return (
    <Button
      key={task.id}
      className="button"
      variant="contained"
      color="secondary"
      size="large"
      onClick={() => toggleCompleted(task.id)}
      disabled={task.completed}
    >
      {task.todo}
    </Button>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Everything you said is spot on, thank you for the help